# Why is a join record being created for this model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a web app for scheduling our company's various site deployments among the developers and product owners on our Scrum team, when we launch updates or improvements. I have two models, `User` and `Release`. A `Release` is a single deployment event. Then I have a join table, called `release_users`. A user has and belongs to many releases. A release has many users, under the name `product_owners`, and belongs to one user, under the name `developer`. The `Release` table has a `developer_id` column which equals the User's ID, so it doesn't involve the `ReleaseUser` association at all (at least, that's what I want).

Here's the problem: when I create a new `Release` record (through the form), it automatically creates/saves a `ReleaseUser` record for the developer in addition to the product owners. When I look at `@release.product_owners`, I see the developer listed under there when it shouldn't be. It should only create ReleaseUser records for product owners. `@release.developer` works as expected, it selects the user from the User table based on `developer_id` and doesn't go through the ReleaseUser table.

So something is wrong in my model configurations I think? Rails is performing some behind-the-scenes magic that I can't pinpoint.

**Code**

release.rb:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :release_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :product_owners, :through => :release_users, :source => :user
  belongs_to :developer, :class_name => "User"
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :release_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :releases, :through => :release_users
end
```

release_user.rb:

```
class ReleaseUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :user
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Developer" %><br>
  <%= f.select :developer_id, options_for_select(User.select_options, selected: @release.selected_option), { include_blank: 'None' } %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Product Owners" %><br>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :product_owner_ids, User.all, :id, :full_name do |b| %>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %> <br/>
    </label>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

releases_controller.rb:

```
# POST /releases
# POST /releases.json
def create
  @release = Release.new(release_params)

  # Release belongs to one developer at most
  unless release_params[:developer_id].empty?
    @developer = User.find(release_params[:developer_id])

    # User has many releases, add to array
    @developer.releases << @release
    @developer.save
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @release.save
      format.html { redirect_to releases_url, notice: 'Release was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @release }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @release.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

(Rails 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
@developer.releases << @release
```

is adding a record to `ReleaseUsers` because you stated that:

```
class User 
   has_many :releases, :through => :release_users
end
```

So by using `@developer.releases << @release` you are telling rails to create that association in the `release_users` table.

It seems you need to isolate the scope for something like `developer_releases` on `User` and then none of the `unless` block is needed.

Something like

```
class User
  # existing relationships
  has_many :developer_releases, class_name: 'Release', foreign_key: :developer_id
end
```

Then the controller code can be slimmed down:

```
def create
  @release = Release.new(release_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @release.save
      format.html { redirect_to releases_url, notice: 'Release was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @release }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @release.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you for explaining the function of `<<` in relation to the join table. I added that because I thought I had to manually set the value of `user.releases` every time a new release was created. The `:developer_releases` relationship is exactly what I needed instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is creating the join table

```
@developer.releases << @release
```

There's no reason to do that. Just take it out.